# Flex XML get Value ( Where is the mistake? )

Tags: xml, apache-flex

i want to acces an Element of an XML. But somehow. i get null as the Result and that does not make any sense to me.
Can you find the mistake ?
[alt text http://img697.imageshack.us/img697/9867/xml.png](http://img697.imageshack.us/img697/9867/xml.png)

Comment: Do you have some code to look at?

Comment: better show the XML fragment and some code as text.  screenshots just don't cut it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way. The only thing I changed was the way you are casting your variables. I'm not going to attempt to recreate your return statement as the screenshot doesn't show enough of it. If this doesn't work please paste in your code and XML as plain text instead of images.

```
private function processFilter(item:Object):Boolean{
  var xmlo:XML = new XML(item);
  var support:String = String(xmlo.Row.Support);
  trace("support is : " + support);
}
```

Comment: A similar variation that I would suggest is:

var support:String = xmlo.Row.Support.toString();